# How does this query work? I am confused in line 1

Tags: sql

Employee

```
===========================
|  Employee ID | Salary    |
===========================
|     3         |  200     |
|     4         |   800    |
|     7         |   450    |
============================
```

Query :

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (1) = (          --Line1
             SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
             FROM Employee Emp2
             WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

The above query outputs the 2nd highest salary for the "Employee" table. 
How does Line1 work? I am not familiar with the syntax type:

```
WHERE (1) =
```

Comment: If result of second select will be equal 1 then you get all records from Employee Emp1 else not equal 1 then you do not get any data

Comment: It's just backwards - it's the same as saying `Where (Select Count(blah) ...) = 1)`  Whoever wrote it probably does `Right Join`s too.

Comment: That's nothing special. Braces can be omnited.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720735/what-does-where-1-mean-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
    FROM Employee Emp2
    WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
 = 1
```

Basically like you said - select all employees with the second highest salary.