# SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 1

Tags: sql, select-query

I've been curious. What are the differences between these respective queries:

1. `` SELECT * FROM `tablename` ``
2. `` SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE 1 ``
3. `` SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE 1=1 ``

Comment: is there a "too narrow" flag for tags? because that applies to many, if not all, SQL dialects. I see it frequently in MSSQL and Oracle as well. btw what are the apostrophes? is not the backtick ` used to quote mysql object names?

Comment: @dlatikay you can edit the tags...

Comment: hm. why not simply `... WHERE TRUE`? I am aware that (in most SQL, including MySQL) TRUE is just a fancy macro for `1` - but still, ain't it a bit more obvious to the reader?

Comment: 2 is invalid in most SQL dialects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would someone use WHERE 1=1 AND <conditions> in a SQL clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242822/why-would-someone-use-where-1-1-and-conditions-in-a-sql-clause)

Comment: I've read about some database systems where you can't use a DELETE without making an explicit condition as a protection against accidentally deleting the whole table. Requiring an always-true condition would mean "Yes, I really do mean delete the whole table."

Comment: 2 is not valid I think in plsql, the other two should produce the same results.

Comment: Just FYI. there's a more appropriate way of achieving this `SELECT *` using `TABLE 'tablename'`.

Comment: I used to use a (1=1) condition as first when developing some complex queries, where each next condition can start with e.g. AND, hence it's easy to comment out line by line

Answer (score 177, accepted):

2 and 3 are the same in MySQL, functionally 1 is also the same.

`where 1` is not standard so, as others have pointed out, will not work in other dialects.

People add `where 1` or `where 1 = 1` so `where` conditions can be easily added or removed to/from a query by adding in/commenting out some "`and` ..." components.

i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE 1=1
--AND Column1 = 'Value1'
AND Column2 = 'Value2'
```

Comment: And also when you are programmatically building a query into a string to execute it later, if you add `WHERE 1=1` you will not need to take care if the condition you are trying to add to the string is the first one (so it will need a `WHERE` in front) or not.

Comment: Been programming for 6 years and never thought of doing this - thanks!

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that this is very different from `ORDER BY 1`, which is discouraged and rather rare: here, the number is the index of the column to sort.

Comment: @dlatikay `ORDER BY 1` syntax is required (instead of column names) if you are doing a union of two or more SELECT statements.

Comment: @SimonGates I've been programming for 6 years and never thought about doing anything else lol

Comment: @WernerCD I think it's far more sensible to build up a list of filter clauses in a list of some kind, and then string join them with `" AND "` as the delimiter.

Comment: @ZevSpitz My experience is more working in a code editor, building the queries by hand for use in a reports - not dynamically building the queries via code. So `WHERE 1=1 \r\n ...` and commas at start of lines are two things I grew attached to real quick.

Comment: Actually, Sql Server throws an error if you use `where 1`

Comment: @ZevSpitz But you still have to conditionally add the `WHERE` keyword depending on whether the list of where clauses is empty.

Comment: @Barmar True, but I think it still makes more sense to do this (when dynamically building an SQL statement in code) than to introduce weird artifacts into the SQL.

Comment: I have bad experiences in the past with SQL engines that either returned the results more quickly with WHERE 1=1 than if there were no where clause and even some that crashed if there were no where clause, so I always add a condition that must be true when I want all the rows.

Comment: @user45959 What RDMS did you use that crashed on a select without a where clause?

Answer (score 76):

As you know, all three produce the same results.  (In a boolean context, MySQL treats the integer "1" as true -- in fact, any number that is not "0" is treated as true).

The MySQL optimizer is explicitly [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html) to remove constant conditions in the `WHERE` clause:

> - Constant condition removal  . . .:
>
>   (B>=5 AND B=5) OR (B=6 AND 5=5) OR (B=7 AND 5=6)
>     -> B=5 OR B=6

Hence, all three will be compiled into exactly the same code.

They are all functionally equivalent and should have the same performance characteristics.

That said, the first and third are standard SQL.  The second will cause some sort of boolean expression error in many databases.  So, I would advise you to avoid that (I'm not sure whether it works or not in MySQL's strict SQL mode).

Often the third is used when constructing dynamic `WHERE` clauses.  It makes it easy to add additional conditions as `AND <condition>` without worrying about lingering `AND`s.

Comment: This is a superior answer for saying everything the other answer does but crucially pointing out the difference that #2 is not ANSI-compliant.

Answer (score 16):

If you are asking about the differences in performances and results, there isn't any , 2 and 3 are the same `WHERE TRUE` , and they will result the same as the first one.

```
1 - SELECT * FROM table_name
```

Results in all the data from `table_name` (no filter)

```
2 - SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 1
```

1 will be evaluated as `TRUE` , therefore - no filter - every record will be returned .

```
3 - SELECT * FROM table_name where 1=1
```

Same as the last one, 1=1 is a `TRUE` expression , therefore - no filter - every record will be selected.

Answer (score 14):

All are the same but 2 and 3 are used to easily handle `AND/OR` conditions 
like:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE 1=1 AND (columnname1 = 'Value' OR columnname2 = 'Value')
```

Answer (score 8):

In 1, MySQL does not need to evaluate any WHERE conditions.

In 2 and 3, the where condition is static and not based on the rows' values. It will be evaluated with boolean logic and always be true.

Functionally, there is no difference. You should choose 1 for code clarity.

Answer (score 7):

All are the same but 2 and 3 are used to create Dynamic queries for AND/OR conditions

```
sqlquery ="  SELECT * FROM `tablename` where 1 =1 "
```

we use  2 and 3 format to make dynamic query so we already know "where" keyword  is added and we keep adding  more filters .
Like

```
sqlquery  = sqlquery + "and columna =a"
"AND columna =a " then
```

after few lines if we have new filters we add  "AND coulmnb =b " and so on

You don't have to check the sql query for where keyword as its placed in first or initial query

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE 1=1 AND (columnname1 = 'Value' OR columnname2 = 'Value')
```

Otherwise  we can write `sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM tablename"`

then

if there is no 'where' clause in `sqlquery`  then

```
sqlquery  = sqlquery + "where columna =a"
```

else

```
sqlquery  = sqlquery + "and columna =a"
```

Comment: 4 leading spaces denote a code block. Please [edit] your answer to format it properly, and see [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for the whole Markdown formatting Bible.

Answer (score 4):

They all output the same answer. However the way 2 and 3 are written is mostly is in order to have control of the "Where" statement so it would make it easier to add it or remove it later.

I think that the first and third way are the proper way of writing it. If you need a where statement you do like in number 3 otherwise number 1 would be good enough.

Answer (score 3):

In MS SQL 1 and 3 are same , however, option 2 will not work , option 2 is an invalid statement as in MS SQL, WHERE is used to compare some values. For Example:

1. Select * from 'myTable where ID = 3 (valid)
2. Select * from 'myTable where 1 = 1 is same as Select * from 'myTable where 2= 2 is same as Select * from 'myTable where 3= 3 you get the idea (valid) is same as Select * From 'myTable'

Answer (score 2):

1. **SELECT * FROM table_name** : it will give you all the records of the
   table with running any where statement.
2. **SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 1** : this where condition is always
   true, its mostly used by hacker to get into any system. If you heard
   about sql injections than 2 & 3 are scenarios which are forced to
   build by hacker to get all the records of table.
3. **SELECT * FROM table_name where 1=1** : This will give you all the
   records of the table but it will compare the where statement and
   then move forward, it's basically added to add or removed more
   statements after that.

Answer (score 1):

**Result** - Gives all the records in the table specified instead of tablename for all three queries

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 1` - Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3720750/6426617)

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 1=1` - Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/242831/6426617)

For more Info about WHERE clause optimizations check these : [MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html), [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html), [SQL](http://oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sql/indexes/where-clause.html)